# Xamarin Forms(PCL) how to get iOS project only and not the android one?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have Xamarin Forms(PCL) project GitHub Sample. I have license for iOS and not for android. I want only iOS project to run. I did unload the android one but the problem is when I build the solution it asks for android license. how can I configure my PCL so that it will work for iOS and will not ask Android license?

Comment: You can use a Xamarin starter license but remember the "app size" or try the license for 30 days.

Comment: Hi I have license for iOS.  problem is I have PCL project sample which I downloaded from GitHub but it contains android project as well. I did unload and tried to build the project still it asks for android license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just right click the Android project and select unload? That should exclude it from the build.

Comment: Please go through the question problem was with my xamarin setup I guess. As I did unload android project from solution. Now it is all working fine.